Lumbroso "dice roller", correctness of the algorithm for 32 bit integers
In this paper
Optimal Discrete Uniform Generation from Coin Flips, and Applications
Lumbroso develop a nice algorithm: The FAST DICE ROLLER algorithm; it returns an integer which is uniformly drawn from the set $\{ 0, . . . , n − 1 \}$ and terminates with probability 1.
The algorithm is written both in a "pseudo high level language, machine agnostic" (page 4) and in plain C (page 20).
In the C version the numbers are represented as 32 bit unsigned integers: uint32_t
so the algo input value n belongs to the set $\{ 0, . . . , 2^{32} - 1 \}$.
It seems to me that the C version is incorrect: if we call it for numbers greater than $2^{31}$, for example

algFDR(1 << 31 + 1)

at the 31 iteration the variable v overflows

v = v << 1;

I need help:

am I correct ?
if yes, is it possible to fix the C implementation? how?

Note for non programmers people: << is the left shift operator, for binary arithmetic.
Example: 1 << 2 means shift 1 by 2 bits, left: result = 4
In general: 1 << n equals to 2 ^ n

ADDENDUM
I fix the C routine, I post it as a solution

Addendum: I think this question is on topic here, because as a programmer I can try and fix the C algorithm to not overflow and return some value... but I don't know how to mantain the uniformity of distribution!

This is an elegant and concise solution.
uint32_t FDR(uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t v = 1, c = 0;
    bool overflow = n >= 0x80000000;

    if (overflow)
    {
        n -= 0x80000000;        // reduce to 31 bit
        c = FDR(0x7fffffff) + FDR(n + 2);
        return c;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        v <<= 1;
        c = (c << 1) | flip();
        if (v >= n)
        {
            if (c < n)
                return c;
            v -= n;
            c -= n;
        }
    }
}



Proof for 8 bit integers:
    n = 255             0 .. 254    
    ----------------------------
    127                 0 .. 126
    (255 - 128) + 2     0 .. 128

    n = 128             0 .. 127
    ----------------------------
    127                 0 .. 126
    (128 - 128) + 2     0 .. 1

Proof for 9 bit integers:
    n = 511             0 .. 510
    ----------------------------
    255                 0 .. 254
    (511 - 256) + 2     0 .. 256

    n = 256             0 .. 255
    ----------------------------
    255                 0 .. 254
    (256 - 256) + 2     0 .. 1

The math is correct, but I am not sure about its statistical properties: does this version keep the author's promises?

I agree the C algorithm is (probably) flawed. The author states the correctness of the program depends on the loop invariant "$c$ is uniformly distributed over $\{0, \dots, v-1\}$." Let us consider a 2-bit system and pass $n = 3$.
# initialization
n = 0b11
v = 0b01
c = 0b00

# after first iteration, flip() returned 0
v = 0b10
c = 0b00

# after second iteration, flip() returned 1
v = 0b00
c = 0b01

and clearly the loop invariant is violated. While this doesn't necessarily invalidate the correctness of the algorithm, it certainly invalidates the author's proof (as it pertains to the C code).

OP asked about the correctness of the C code... I show the linchpin of the author's "proof" does not hold in the C code.

Yes. My comment was only intended to apply to an earlier version of your answer which said that your example "invalidates the author's proof" without any further qualification.

(A) "Am I Correct ?" :
Yes , there is a Corner-Case Bug in the C Code.
Consider 32Bit numbers like this :
$v=00000000000000000000000000000001$
$c=00000000000000000000000000000000$
$n=10001000100000010000100001000001$
The Algorithm keeps "Doubling" $v$ until it becomes larger than $n$
The max $v$ is like this :
$v=10000000000000000000000000000000$
$c=\ \ \ \ \ \text{?????}\ \ \ \ \ $
$n=10001000100000010000100001000001$
Since it is still less than $n$ , $v$ sill be "Doubled" , though that will overflow.
(B) "Possible C Code fix" :
Solution-1 is to let $v$ hold a larger Bit-Pattern.
Change this
uint32_t v = 1, c = 0;
to this
uint64_t v = 1, c = 0;
Now if(v >= n) will have no Issues with overflow.
Naturally , we will have to use type-casting :
if(c < n) return (uint32_t) c;
Initial :
$v=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001$
$c=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$
$n=10001000100000010000100001000001$
Earlier Max value :
$v=0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000$
$c=\ \ \ \ \ \text{?????}\ \ \ \ \ $
$n=10001000100000010000100001000001$
Earlier overflow value , which will not overflow now :
$v=0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000$
$c=\ \ \ \ \ \text{?????}\ \ \ \ \ $
$n=10001000100000010000100001000001$
Now $v$ has rightly exceeded $n$ , hence algorithm will wok out.
Alternative ways to fix the Issue using union & temporary uint32_t variable & etc will work too.
ADDENDUM :
Solution-2 is to handle 32 Bit overflow case mathematically , to get the correct calculation without overflow.
Here is a way to fix that case without 64 Bit Integers :

inline uint32_t algFDR(unsigned int n)
{
  uint32_t v = 1, c = 0;
  while(true)
  {
    c = (c << 1) + flip();
    int v_overflow = 0 ;
    if (v && (1 << 31)) v_overflow=1 else v_overflow=0 ; /* checking for overflow to occur */

    if (v_overflow)
    { /* handle overflow situation without overflow */
      uint32_t v_temp1 = v, v_temp2 = v, v_temp3 = v, n_temp = n;
      /* we know that 2v >= n */
      if (c<n) return c;
      else
      { /* both v & n have Bit 31 , which we will remove */
        v_temp1=v_temp1-(1 << 31) ;
        n_temp=n_temp-(1 << 31) ;
        v_temp2=v_temp2-n_temp; /* no issues here : v_temp2 (with Bit 31) is larger than n_temp (without Bit 31) */
        v_temp3=v_temp2+v_temp1; /* Equivalent to 2v-n=v+v-n=v+(v-Bit31)-(n-Bit31)=(v-Bit31)+v-(n-Bit31) */
        /* all calculations are thus completed without overflow */
        c=c-n;
        v=v_temp3;
        /* In case , we want to handle overflow in c , we can try the Exact Same */
      }
    }
    else
    { /* continue with no change */
      v = v << 1;
      if(v >= n)
      {
        if(c < n) return c;
        else
        {
          v = v - n;
          c = c - n;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



Hi Prem. Thanks for you analysis. Unfortunately I didn't specify: the target machine are microcontrollers, without a uint64 data type. Without resorting to unions, isn't it possible to "mangle" the variables (v, c, n) and completing the algo using 32 bit values?

I have added a way to make the computations with 32Int , without using 64Bit Int. Do let me know , @Massimo , whether you want me to add some text explanations.

Solution-1 uses 64 Bit Int with no overflow automatically , @Massimo , while Solution-2 uses 32 Bit Int with extra code for handling overflow cases.

Hi @Prem. Sorry but I your C solution is wrong. It is possible flip() will return 32 times 1... so also c overflows.

Please remove the flawed code or I have to downvote.

Well , I did add this comment "/* In case , we want to handle overflow in c , we can try the Exact Same */" in the C code. Adding that extra C Code to handle variable c is easy , though it will hide & confuse what I am trying with the logic given there. Do you think , @Massimo , that v overflow is handled correctly ? If yes , then will the Same not work for handling c overflow too ?

In other words , to make it clear , we have to use int c_overflow; & int c_newbit=flip(); & then calculate c+c-n+c_newbit using a couple of temp variables in the Same Way to avoid overflow !
